# ionic - how to put ion-select and ion-datetime together in ion-item row

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to put ion-select and ion-datetime together in the same ion-item like below:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let column of columns">
            <ion-label floating>{{column.title}}</ion-label>

             <ion-select *ngIf="column.type=='customDate'"> 
                        <ion-option value="on">on</ion-option>
                        <ion-option value="onorbefore">on or before</ion-option>
                        <ion-option value="onorafter">on or after</ion-option>
                        <ion-option value="bewteen">between</ion-option>
                    </ion-select>

                    <ion-datetime *ngIf="column.type=='customDate'"  displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" ></ion-datetime>
                    <ion-datetime *ngIf="column.type=='customDate'"  displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" ></ion-datetime>



            <ion-input *ngIf="column.type=='text'" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="filterValues[column.id]"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

The logic is if the column type is customDate, then show dropdown select and two datetime pickers. Based on the user selected dateType, the second dateTime picker will be hidden.

Now the problem is if I use above code, then I can ONLY see the dateTime component. The dateType dropdown select is no longer there. I looked at the source code in web console, the dropdown dateType select is empty.

Are there any restrictions for using the ion-item component? why can't you display all three together in the same ion-item row?

Thanks

Comment: `ion-item` is so hard to custom. In that case, I usually use `div` instead of it

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-row>
  <ion-col ion-item col-6>
     <ion-select></ion-select>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col ion-item col-6>
     <ion-datetime></ion-datetime>
  </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
</ion-list>
```